# Why don't electrons in parallel battery circuits repel?

Tags: power-electronics, physics, electron

Here is a short snecdote, which will give a good explanation into my question.

I was in a science class, and we were doing a circuit with a very small filament light bulb, and some AAA batteries. I connected around 2 AAA batteries in parallel, as opposed to series, and I was promptly chastised, as apparently, in her words, I risked shorting her batteries. I have used batteries in parallel before, and I have never faced this issue.

[image]

Here is an example circuit, with the junctions I am confused about marked A, and B.
Now, from physics I learned that electrons have a negative charge, and that they repel, so why don't the electrons flowing from the cathodes of each cell repel when they meet ay A, and also later when they arrive at B?
I cannot find any explanation anywhere, and I was wondering if any of you amazingly smart people here could help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The individual electrons do repel each other, yes. But the overall flow of current in a wire doesn't really get repelled like that. The flow of electrons will follow the electric field, generally in the direction the field becomes more positive. In this case, the important factor is the voltage on the cells. Without a load, whichever cell has a lower voltage will see current flowing through it backwards, and this can be a problem if the battery isn't designed to handle it.

Connecting batteries in parallel is commonly done in large battery packs.  Since it is possible for cells to fail shorted, battery packs built with parallel cells usually include some sort of per-cell fusing.  Here is a picture of cells wire-bonded in a battery pack, similar to what's used in Tesla cars (picture from https://chargedevs.com/features/a-closer-look-at-wire-bonding/):

[image: Wire-bonded cells]

In this case, the wire bonds act as fuses and will melt to disconnect a shorted cell.

Comment: So If I had two new AAA Batteries, a Parralel Connection would be good, and if I used 1 New, and 1 used AAA Battery, It wouldn't be good?

Comment: Maybe.  Even two new batteries can have slightly different voltages and will attempt to equalize when connected in parallel.  It's usually a good idea to avoid this type of setup unless you really know what you're doing and you fully understand the battery characteristics.  It's also usually a better idea to do this with rechargeable batteries as they are at least designed to handle reverse (charging) current.

Comment: So, I am currently doing a project with 2x Series 18650 (Rechargeable) in parallel. Is this setup safe?

Comment: If you're using 18650 cells, you're probably fine.  There may be something to be said for adding a small series resistance to each cell to limit the max current, but the cells will have their own internal resistance so relying on the internal resistance may be sufficient unless you're using cells with particularly low internal resistance.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that it is possible for cells to fail shorted.  In this case, the failed cell will discharge all of the cells that are in parallel.  This can be mitigated by placing a fuse of some sort in series with each battery, so that the fuse blows if the cell fails short.  For a prototype or school project, this probably isn't something to worry about.

Comment: @Oskar, I'm not an expert, but I wouldn't worry about that. In consumer electronics, you have millions of devices that use exactly that -- non-rechargeable AA(A) battery packs in parallel. If this was a BadIdea(TM) as many here claim, they surely wouldn't be doing it at such a massive scale.

Answer (score -1):

Why do electrons not repel?

If you're referring to the known fact that Van de Graaf generators are built with a ball at the top, where the electrons supposedly spread evenly all across the spherical surface (because they repel), mind the difference in Voltage. Your battery cells can have 1.5 to 3 Volts per cell. The Van de Graaf can produce a couple dozen to a couple hundred kiloVolt, depending on size and construction.

In other words: your battery cell is a harmless and dependable workhorse - produces low voltage and some noteworthy current. In contrast, the Van de Graaf operates with "static" electricity = high voltage charges, but next to zero current (until someone ventures: allright, let's try at what distance this goes ZZzap :-)